# Can Willbender be used when Dark Salvation is cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Willbender](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWillbender%5d) be used when [Dark Salvation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDark%20Salvation%5d) is cast?

I only ask as it mentions the word target twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on how it was cast.

The spell asks you to select 1 target player and 0-1 target creatures:

> **Target player** creates X 2/2 black Zombie creature tokens, then **up to one target creature** gets -1/-1 until end of turn for each Zombie that player controls.

If you cast it without targeting a creature, then it has only one target and may be retargeted by Willbender. If you decide to use the creature-removal part of the spell, then it has two targets and is not a valid target for Willbender's ability.

Willbender's abilities does not add or subtract targets, so you cannot target a token-generating Dark Salvation to use it as removal (you can, however, steal the tokens).

Here's a bit of relevant comp rules that [Michael Politowski](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/8520/micha%C5%82-politowski) pointed out in the comments (emphasis added):

> 114.8c An object that looks for a “[spell or ability] that targets only [something]” **checks the number of different objects or players that became the target of that spell or ability when it was put on the stack** (as modified by effects that changed those targets), not the number of those objects or players that are currently legal targets…

---

Thus, if you're playing EDH and your opponent has a morph in play, I very much suggest using Dark Salvation to its full effect so you don't get Willbender'd. Because the first rule of EDH is "It's Always a Willbender."

Comment: Obligatory Comprehensive Rules reference: [114.8a](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Target)